# CLion Installation Problems on a Mac

Tags: macos, installation, clion

Every time I attempt to open JetBrains' CLion after moving it into my applications folder, it gives me a message saying ""CLion" will damage your computer. You should move it to the Trash." This is on my MacBook Pro and OS X El Capitan. What particularly perplexes me is that every other Jetbrains IDE works perfectly. Any help would be appreciated, as I have yet to find anything whatsoever elsewhere that could solve this.

Comment: Just a thought, and therefore comment rather than an answer, but maybe try installing it with `homebrew` - it is a great package manager for OSX and I use it for everything... I can see that it can install `CLion` - I ran `brew search clion` and it shows a package.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll try it out tomorrow and report back posthaste!

Comment: @MarkSetchell no dice on homebrew unfortunately :/ I'm unfamiliar with it and the terminal commands so it's entirely possible that I am simply going about it the wrong way